# Is it possible to preserve original images in order to change image size later?

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

I want to create a simple wordpress blog site. At the moment I will use a template, but I would like to develop my own afterwards. And I have one concern related to images.

Current template has nice big images and no sidebar, but in my future template I will definitely have a sidebar, which means that I will have to change image dimensions.

My main question - is there a good way to change image dimensions without using css? I wouldn't like to re-create all posts after I change template, because there will be a lot of them.

For example, images at the moment are 900px wide (height is not as important), but in the future template I plan that I will need to change image width to 600px. I would prefer not to do it with css's "max-width".

Perhaps there is a tool that can preserve original image and then re-create them with new dimensions afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is trivial in WordPress.

Whenever you upload image WP keeps original file and generates additional *sizes* from it. Several of the sizes are built–in (see Settings > Media > Image sizes) and any additional ones can be added with [`add_image_size()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/).

So when you develop your own theme as part of the process you:

1. Determine image size you need.
2. Register that image size and use it in the theme.
3. WP will generate the size from existing originals for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Wow. I didn't even realize this would be so easy.
In which folder are original images kept by the way?

Comment: `wp-content/uploads` by default.

Comment: 1. Hmm, I always thought that those are thumbnails instead of original. Where does wordpress store generated images then?

2. Also, regarding your original reply. Wouldn't it mean that I will have to open each post and re-apply each featured image, in order for new image size to be applied?

Comment: Originals are stored too, that's what my answer says. Both are stored side by side in uploads. If you want to change _existing_ size there are plenty of tools that can do that (search for regenerate image sizes).